# How can I implement 3-way relationship (reference) between entities?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have 3 entities: A,B — node types, C — user.
Node A has 2 reference fields, one to B and one to C.
What I need is to show in a view all B nodes for a certain C, which has a relation A-B=A-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Relation module](http://drupal.org/project/relation) should be ideal for that. It allows you to create a single relation entity that links 3 (or more) entities together. It's in beta and you may have to do some work to get the user interface you need (I say that based on the [Relation session at DrupalCon London](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/relation)), but it's flexibility is superior to any other relation/reference module out there.

Comment: I thought on that, but I'm not quiet sure If it is ready for production. Still I'm going to try your suggestion and write about the results in this thread.

Comment: Great, I'd love to read how it works for you.

Comment: My experience with Relation module was very successful. Thank you! I was able to create very flexible architecture with it's help. This module seems as a very fundamental approach for Drupal's future. Although in my case I've stumbled with no stable release for Relation Select, I solved it with the help of time-tested Node Reference UI for end-user and set of Rules for creating relation entity with references fields values.